# How to assign zero values to multiple columns in a data.frame in r within a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a loop that splits a dataset (FULLDATASET) into a training (OLDData) and holdout (NewData)dataset. A Model (auto.arima with (xtreg)regressors) is estimated on 24 pieces indexed by i.  The holdout dataset (NewData) is used to make predictions using the FIT from the model built on the OldData. NewData2 is the exact same as NewData, except I want three of the predictors in columns 18:20 to take on zero values. When I run the loop, I get no errors, but NewData2's variables in column's 18 thru 20 have the same original values, and thus my predictions are the same using both NewData and NewData2. When I specify the variables by name it will assign a vector of zeros to only the first specified variable.

```
OldData<-FULLDATASET[[i]][1:525,]
NewData<-FULLDATASET[[i]][526:547,]
NewData2<-transform(FULLDATASET[[i]][526:547,],FULLDATASET[[i]][526:547,18:20]<-0 )
```

My question is: How do I transform a dataframe so that I can assign zero values to more than one column in the dataframe? Also, remember my code is running in a loop. I originally used plyr and apply functions but for my needs my loop executes much faster.

Comment: Don't use `transform`. Just `FULLDATASET[[i]][526:547,18:20] <- 0` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't use `<-` inside an argument function. Use `=` instead.

2) The second argument of `transform` needs to be a column name.

3) The easiest solution to your problem is in two steps:

```
NewData2 = FULLDATASET[[i]][526:547,]
NewData2[,18:20] = 0
```